# Load home page when coming in with parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, fancybox

I've got a WordPress based site that shows posts in popup using Fancybox v.2. Apparently, the only way to trigger Fancybox is to click `a` tag with certain callback classes.

So there it is:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/?p=<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="filmloop various fancybox.iframe">
```

But, when I'm coming back to website by direct permalink it loads single.php as a separate page without popup. So the way around is to put parameter in direct URL, grab it when coming back reload page, put the grabbed url into anchor and trigger click. The only problem is how to hack WordPress to reload page after grabbing parameter.

Here's what I've got, in single.php:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
```

I grab parameter. Then:

```
window.location.replace("http://someurl.com");
```

And here's the tricky part. How can I store parameter for later use when page will be redirected. Is this way of thinking even possible, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a click when the page has loaded

```
$(document).ready(function{}
    $('somelink').trigger('click');
});
```

That way you can target the link on the page that instantiates FancyBox.

Comment: That I know. I even have a dummy anchor prepared and function, that puts url in href and triggers click.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want to trigger Fancybox on initial page load?  If so then you don't have to trigger it on a link which actually goes anywhere, I guess you know that but with your question it's not very clear.  You can make the link that triggers Fancybox do nothing other than act as a listener for fancybox like so
`<a href="javascript:void(0);">Open Fancybox</a>`
I'm not sure what other stuff you need to put in to trigger fancybox from a link but add than and hide the link with css and then trigger a click on it like I showed you above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code . Just replace ?p=123 to #123 and trigger :D

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      if(document.URL.indexOf("#")==-1) // If hash not present in url
            {
               if(document.URL.indexOf("?p=") > -1){ // Check if url has parameter ?p=
            var parameter = document.URL.split('?p=');
                    myhash = "#"+parameter[1];
            window.location.replace(parameter[0]+myhash)
                    }
            }
            else {
             // We got hash 
             // Now trigger
            var n = document.URL.split('#');
            href = "http://buffermow.com?p="+n[1];
            findHref = 'a[href="'+href+'"]';
            mylinktotrigger = $(findHref);
            $(mylinktotrigger).trigger('click');
            }
        });
</script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="http://buffermow.com?p=123" onclick="alert('its Done');" class="filmloop various fancybox.iframe">My fancy link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```